# limit proof at a point. Spivak, Chapter 5 problem 36b.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Prove that $\lim_{x\to0^-} f(\frac{1}{x})=L$ iff $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=L$

Proof

$(\leftarrow)$

Suppose that  $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=L$ Let $\epsilon>0$ then there exists a real number $N<0$ such that if $x<N$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. If $0<-x<\frac{-1}{N}$ then $\frac{-1}{x}>-N\implies \frac{1}{x}<N\implies |f(1/x)-L|<\epsilon$. Thus $\lim_{x\to0^-} f(\frac{1}{x})=L$

$(\rightarrow)$

Suppose $\lim_{x\to0^-} f(\frac{1}{x})=L$. Let $\epsilon>0$ then there exists a $\delta>0$ and $0<0-x<\delta$ then $|f(\frac{1}{x})-L|<\epsilon$. Let $x>\frac{1}{\delta}\implies \frac{1}{x}<\delta \implies |f(\frac{1}{{\frac{1}{x}}})-L|=|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. THus  $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=L$.

Would this proof be correct?

Comment: Is there a question? If you're asking for proof-verification, please say so!

Comment: yeah i need proof verification.